# multiple forms ng-repeat - posting back the current $scope only, not whole object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have multiple forms using ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="individual in orderDetails track by $index">
    <form ng-submit="saveDetails();">
      <input ng-model="individual.order.statusText">
      <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's an example of what's stored in my object, for each **individual** (IE - object) in **OrderDetails**.

```
orderDetails {
    object{
        foo {},
        bar {},
        order {}
    },
    object{
        foo {},
        bar {},
        order {}
    }       
}
```

Now I'm referencing the data with **individual** in my repeater, how can I submit only the order from a single **individual** when posting back to the server, as opposed to the whole **orderDetails** object?

Here is my save function, for the form submit button

```
$scope.saveDetails = function(data, status) {               

    ordersService.updateOrder($scope.orderDetails.individual.order)

    // once submitted update the whole model on the page again
    .success(function(data, status) {                   
        $scope.orderDetails = data;                 
    })                         
}
```

And here is my service:

```
getData.updateOrder = function(data){
    var url = '/service/rest/orders';

    return $http.post(url, data)                    

    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('Error fetching feed:', status, headers, config);
    });
};            

return getData;
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: question is not very clear... just tell us what html look like and relevant code... also does the background that it was working really relevant in the question? may be create a plunker with minimal code

Comment: Apologies @entre, it's hard to explain. I've refined my question based on your suggestions, does this make more sense? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, pass the `individual` object into the submit handler, eg

```
$scope.saveDetails = function(individual) {
    ordersService.updateOrder(individual.order).success(function(data) {
        $scope.orderDetails = data;
    });
};
```

and in your HTML

```
<form ng-submit="saveDetails(individual)">
```

---

To override the `individual` order with the new data, you could just write it back into `individual`, eg

```
.success(function(data) {
    angular.extend(individual, data); // or angular.merge for deep extending
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much @phil, that is submitting now! A simple solution, too. Do you know how to load the data back into the scope? "$scope.orderDetails" contains all orders, whereas the data contains just the individual order. It breaks the model currently on success. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I worked it out, instead of using "$scope.orderDetails = data;", I used "$scope.orderDetails.push(data);". Cheers!

Comment: @Desmond I've also added another way

Comment: @Desmond you're welcome. If you're unit testing, you'll find passing the required parameters into your scope functions much easier to write tests for.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, that's good to know. Still an Angular newbie and trying to get my head around unit testing, I'll make sure to do that.